# Multiple threads and secure web requests in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a function that requests historical data in KDB from a web endpoint. I'm trying to make parallel requests.

When I make `GET` requests using the main thread (using `each`), it works fine. I have configured KDB to support TLS.

When I do it using sub-threads via `peach` (or processes, I'm not sure what is happening under the hood), I get `'conn. OS reports: Protocol not available`. I've verified the threads are getting the correct URL handle.

Currently I have `\S` and `\s` both as `16i`.

Should I be able to access the web from threads, using SSL?

My best guess is that while SSL is enabled in the main thread, it doesn't seem to be for child threads, and I'm not sure how to convince it otherwise.

Comment: You could look at socket sharding across multiple processes for course load balancing https://code.kx.com/q/wp/socket-sharding

Comment: My understanding is that this is for incoming connections, not outgoing ones?

Comment: Ah sorry yes.  Your issue is listed as a restriction in docs:  
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/ssl/#suitability-and-restrictions

Comment: Oh, that's painful! Thanks so much for pointing that out, much appreciated!